# Are the CV views statistics broken again?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, views

My CV view stats have show the exact same numbers for the past several days. Today (the 1st of Sept) it shows 1 view today, 3 views this week and 10 views this month, which isn't possible.

I see a post from March where the tracking pixels got messed up. Is this the same thing?

Comment: Well, it is possible if you consider "week" to be the last 7 days, and "month" to be the last 30/31 days. I'm not positive that's how it works, though.

Comment: I suppose I'm expecting it to work like SO's stat at the top of the page next to the user id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tim Stone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150235/tim-stone) is correct, they are rolling windows:

Views Today: last 24 hours
Views This Week: last 7 days
Views This Month: last 30 days

Comment: would it be better for it to work like SO's stat at the top of the page next to the user id?  It seems like it would be better that way unless there's no other statistical page to look into activity.